# Global sections of twisted ideal sheaves of distinct sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $D$ be set of $n$ distinct points in projective space $\mathbb{P}^N$, over field $\mathbb{C}$. Then I would like to know $h^0(I_D(m))$. This is just ask that number of linear independent degree $m$ polynomials vanishing on $D$. When $m$ is very large, this should have codimension $n$ in $h^0(O(m))$. My question is how small can $m$ be?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Since $h^0(\mathcal O(m)) = \binom{m+n}{n}$, do you ask for which $m$ one has $\binom{m+n}{n} - n \geq 0$?

Comment: @Marktmeister Oh maybe I should writing it in this way. By the long exact sequence of cohomoology, I want to know when $h^1(I_D(m))=0$? This is true for $m$ is big enough as $O(1)$ is ample.

Comment: There are two $n$s in your question, the number of points and the the dimension of the projective space. Did you mean that?

Comment: @Mohan Sorry. I update.

Comment: The smallest $m$ will depend not just on $n$, but its configurations. For example, I suggest you try four points on a line in the plane as opposed to 4 points of intersections of two smooth conics in the plane. (So, here $n=4, N=2$).